# Git bundle single commit?

Tags: git

I want to [apply a patch including its commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30503140/1695680), how do I bundle a single commit and apply it?

Given example history:

```
0a8b835 intel_pmc_ipc: Add Intel Apollo Lake PMC IPC driver
0d44b41 tc1100-wmi: Delete an unnecessary check before the function call "kfree"
b8830a4 dell-laptop: Fix allocating & freeing SMI buffer page
2ec1e9e target: Bump core version to v5.0
```

- Say I wanted to bundle `0d44b41` as `001.bundle`, and apply it?
- Say I wanted to bundle `b8830a4`-through-`0d44b41` as `002.bundle`, and apply it?

*Note: I can already do this with patch files, but I want to also include the commit mes automatically.*

I tried to follow the [git-scm doc on bundle](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/10/bundles.html) with this command, which fails as:

```
$ git bundle create 001.bundle 0d44b41^ 0d44b41 
fatal: Refusing to create empty bundle.
```

Comment: ...and `git am` to apply the patches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want specifically to limit yourself to `git bundle`, but assuming you *do* want that, take note of this wording in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html):

> *`git-rev-list-args`*
>
> > A list of arguments, acceptable to `git rev-parse` and `git rev-list` (and containing a named ref, see **SPECIFYING REFERENCES** below), that specifies the specific objects and references to transport. ...
>
> **SPECIFYING REFERENCES**
>
> > `git bundle` will only package references that are shown by `git show-ref`:
> >            this includes heads, tags, and remote heads.

Now consider your command:

> ```
> $ git bundle create 001.bundle 0d44b41^ 0d44b41
> ```

The `create 001.bundle` specifies the file to create.  The remainder of your command-line, `0d44b41^ 0d44b41`, are the *`git-rev-list-args`*.  What reference (branch or tag name) did you use here?<sup>1</sup>

---

Note that `git format-patch` includes commit messages (and author), and using `git am` will apply the commit including the original message (and author, though you will be the committer unless you do some additional setup work).

---

<sup>1</sup>Rhetorical question, of course: you did not use any.  I'm not sure why `git bundle` is so very insistent on one, since you can easily attach a reference to a raw SHA-1, make the bundle, then remove the reference again without disturbing the just-created bundle.  That would allow you to do what you're attempting.  Or, of course, if there is a name (branch or tag for instance) pointing to the single commit you want bundled, you can use that existing name directly.

Comment: Much thanks, I was unaware that `git am` did what I wanted, as the [SO page I got `git bundle` from](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30503140/1695680) claimed it was _the_way to package a commit.

Comment: This is git, there are always at least a dozen ways to do everything, six of them wrong and three more really painful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), "[`git bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8b48981987956d7cb10c5d7cddbf08d5837bc753/Documentation/git-bundle.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle))</sup> does not lose refs whey they point at the same object.

See [commit 5bb0fd2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bb0fd2cab5a18bc188c8154097857f51a0e9feb), [commit ce1d6d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce1d6d9f1641d87a66c3933255531ee2c15d3143), [commit 9901164](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9901164d81dfc2e050860f7dd60e5590c3cfaa50) (11 Jan 2021) by [Jiang Xin (`jiangxin`)](https://github.com/jiangxin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8b48981](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b48981987956d7cb10c5d7cddbf08d5837bc753), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce1d6d9f1641d87a66c3933255531ee2c15d3143): lost objects when removing duplicate pendings
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jiang Xin</sup>

> [`git rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce1d6d9f1641d87a66c3933255531ee2c15d3143/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup> will list one commit for the following command:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-list 'main^!'
> <tip-commit-of-main-branch>
> ```
>
> But providing the same rev-list args to [`git bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce1d6d9f1641d87a66c3933255531ee2c15d3143/Documentation/git-bundle.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle))</sup>, fail to create a bundle file.
>
> ```
> $ git bundle create - 'main^!'
> # v2 git bundle
> -<OID> <one-line-message>
>
> fatal: Refusing to create empty bundle.
> ```
>
> This is because when removing duplicate objects in function `object_array_remove_duplicates()`, one unique pending object which has the same name is deleted by mistake.
>
> The revision arg '`main^!`' in the above example is parsed by `handle_revision_arg()`, and at lease two different objects will be appended to `revs.pending`, one points to the parent commit of the "`main`" branch, and the other points to the tip commit of the "`main`" branch.
> These two objects have the same name "`main`".
> Only one object is left with the name "`main`" after calling the function `object_array_remove_duplicates()`.
>
> And what's worse, when adding boundary commits into pending list, we use one-line commit message as names, and the arbitrary names may surprise `git-bundle`.
>
> Only comparing objects themselves ("`.item`") is also not good enough, because user may want to create a bundle with two identical objects but with different reference names, such as: "`HEAD`" and "`refs/heads/main`".
>
> Add new function `contains_object()` which compare both the address and the name of the object.