# How do you fake git pull when the network is down?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-am

I don't have network connectivity to allow git fetch to work, but I do have remote desktop access so I am trying to use git format-patch and git am to transfer the commits.

However it appears that the patch gets a new commit number when applied, so you'd end up having to do a merge when the network is restored.

Is it possible to get the effect of a pull by transferring patch files?

Comment: You're looking for [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/11792671/7976758

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that. That transfers the entire repo though which in my case is not huge (so git bundle is a workable solution). Is there some way to transfer just the missing commits?

Comment: You can [git-bundle a single commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31332220/7976758) or as much as you need — an entire branch or just a few commits and tags…

Comment: To expand phd's comment a bit: a bundle file is suitable as input to `git fetch`. It consists of everything `git fetch` *would* get if the network *were* up. The problem is that without the network being up, *you* must tell the sending side (where you make the bundle) what commits the receiving side does and does not have, instead of the receiving side telling the sending side directly. So you give `git bundle` a set of names or hash IDs that the receiver *does* have, and a set of *names the receiver should update*, and the sender builds the bundle from that.

Comment: Thanks @phd - that's exactly what I need. And thanks for the elaboration torek.

Comment: If the network is down, what about faking your origin to your local filesystem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603671/how-to-add-a-local-repo-and-treat-it-as-a-remote-repo?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @gumol - that won't help because the source repo is not in my local filesystem.